# Has Ajax been implemented correctly in Firefox? Synchronous issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

Please take a look at the following code, do you think which log will be printed first?
In Chrome & IE, "sync ajax call: success" is showed first which is expected,
BUT in FF(tested in FF 3.6 & FF 17.0), "async ajax call: success" is showed first instead,
which means although we make the second one as a sychronous call, but when its onreadystatechange was triggered, the handler of asychronous(first) ajax call was executed earliar than that of sychronous(second) ajax call, does it make sense?
Isn't it a firefox bug?

```
// first ajax call, Note: this is asynchronous.
$.ajax({
    url: "/rest/someUrl",
    async : true,
    dataType : "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log("async ajax call: success");
    },
    error : function(data) {
    }
})
// second ajax call, Note: this is synchronous.
$.ajax({
    url: "/rest/someUrl",
    async : false,
    dataType : "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log("sync ajax call: success");
    },
    error : function(data) {
    }
})
```

Comment: Add another `alert` at the end of the code you've shown. It should show after the "sync call" one, but before the "async" one. If it comes first, then Firefox isn't supporting the sync call. That said, you should never use sync calls.

Comment: Actually, the "async call" comes first...
So shouldn't we use sync call anymore?! that's disappointing!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to implement something "correctly" , there must be some specification.

Inside the specification I haven't found any reference to the fact that all scripts should stop executing as long as the synchronous request isn't finished(note that the async-XHR is already running when the sync-XHR starts).

But I found this:

1. [Each XMLHttpRequest object has its own task source. Namely, the XMLHttpRequest task source.](http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#xmlhttprequest-task-source)
     --**both requests represent a single task-source**--
2. [When a user agent is to queue a task, it must add the given task to one of the task queues of the relevant event loop. [...] tasks from different task sources may be placed in different task queues.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#definitions-1)
    --**both tasks may be added to the same task-queue, but must not**--
3. [An event loop must continually run through the following steps for as long as it exists:

   1.Run the oldest task on one of the event loop's task queues, if any, [...]. The user agent may pick any task queue.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#processing-model-4)
    --**he picks now the task-queue where he puts on the  synchronous request**

When I not misunderstood this, and my logic is not wrong, this could be going on:

Firefox puts both XHR on the same queue, IE and chrome put them onto different task-queues.

All browsers run now the task-queue where they placed the synchronous XHR.

- In IE and chrome the synchronous  XHR is the oldest task in his queue and runs
- In FF the asynchronous XHR is the oldest in his queue  and runs

Both implementations seem to be correct.

Comment: Maybe I should use "differently" instead of "incorrectly".  
I think what FF has implemented is quite confusing, suppose I yield the thread intentionally using a async ajax call, and the success handler is supposed to be executed until there is a setTimeout/async ajax call, but the fact is that an sync ajax call will also invoke my success handler, then disorder my design...What's your suggestion s to solve this kind of problem? Thank u in advance.

Comment: Would it be an option to change the order of the XHR-calls(sync before async)?